# Storing utf-8 data in a text field in SQLite results in BLOB content

Tags: c++, sqlite, utf-8, insert

I'm trying to save some form data that are in UTF-8 format in a sqlite database.I'm binding the input using

```
int bindText(int index, const char *text, void func(void*)) {
    return sqlite3_bind_text(comp_stat, index, text, -1, func);
}
```

and the compiled statement is a simple INSERT query.

```
"INSERT INTO `tbl` (`id`,...`,`title`) VALUES (?,...,?);
```

and the CREATE statement is

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
`id`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
...,
`title` TEXT
);
```

The query runs and everything is fine except for that if the input string is a non-ASCII utf-8 string, I won't be able to retrieve it in, and SQLite Browser also shows that field as BLOB and not TEXT anymore. I also hopelessly tried sqlite3_bind_text16 as someone suggested, and of course the result was not OK, but this time it was a garbled text in a totally different UTF-8 code page, but the field was TEXT again, not BLOB.

If I use simple abcd characters everything works fine, so there is no fundamental problem in my queries I guess. Any help is appreciated.

---

OK. There was a problem in my tests, and now I have much more accurate info!

This works:
        cs->bindText ( 12, u8"سلام", sfree);

but this fails (BLOB):
        cs->bindText ( 12, (std::string(u8"سلام")).c_str(), sfree);

What is my problem? Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried using `sqlite3_bind_text64()` with the `SQLITE_UTF8` flag?

Comment: Please expand on your problem statement _"I won't be able to retrieve it in"_

Comment: What is a "UTF-8 code page"?

Comment: @PaulSanders just tried it, no difference with sqlite3_bind_text, result is a BLOB field.

Comment: `sqlite3_bind_text()` requires that the string is encoded in UTF-8. Possibly this SQLite Browser program can't render UTF-8 text? Is it visible in other tools like the command line sqlite3 shell? What does `SELECT typeof(title) FROM tbl` report about the type of the values?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Means a different glyph/character set. Each language has its own code page in the UTF-8 character set.

Comment: @Shawn  I thouoght so at first, but when I set the field in SQLite Browser itself by hand and type the utf-8 characters, it is stored correctly, shown correctly, and retrieved correctly with SELECT.

Comment: Okay that's... not what "code page" means. The whole point of Unicode is to do away with code pages. It's _one_ character set. That's the whole point. If you're seeing unexpected characters (due to reencoding or misencoding) then just say that. :)

Comment: @Shawn interestingly, the query you suggested returns TEXT for all records. Any guess?

Comment: Are you sure *that* text is actually UTF-8? This does sound like a character set issue where your program is using a single-byte character encoding instead of UTF-8.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for sharing your information, but this is actually irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: It could _be_ the problem!

Comment: @Shawn Please tell me is this ok according to what you say or not:         cs->bindText ( 12, u8"سلام", sfree);

Comment: @Shawn I'm quite puzzled, but I also I can't get the values when I run the query in my code too, while I get the UTF-8 values that I stored using SQLite Browser.

Comment: @Shawn please check the additional info. Thanks!

Comment: @Shawn I think I understood the problem. The c_str pointer is being freed before running the query. Many thanks anyway.

Comment: `cs->bindText ( 12, (std::string(u8"سلام")).c_str(), sfree);`? Uh... yeah, that has issues. You're storing a pointer to a temporary value that's deleted at the end of the expression, meaning using that pointer is undefined. Depending on what `sfree` is, there's more problems - with the u8 literal example too, come to think of it, if it's trying to free memory.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. My code wasn't this exactly, and I was getting the c_str from another library, that was why I didn't check whether it remains there or not! But this test led me to checking that. Thanks man.